# Issue with StackNavigator: Route 'X' should declare a screen

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-router

The specific error is "Route 'Camera' should declare a screen".

I have index.js which imports Camera.js and renders the camera component. Camera.js imports router.js which imports all of my screens and creates a StackNavigator. I'm new to React so there's probably something I'm not understanding. Here's the code...

**Index.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { CameraView } from './screens/Camera'

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return <CameraView />;
  }
}

export default App;
```

**Camera.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Button,
} from 'react-native';
import { AppStack } from '../config/router';

....

export default class CameraView extends Component {
    viewProducts = () => {
        this.props.navigation.navigate('Products');
    };
    render() {
        const { navigate } = navigation;
        return (
           <View style={styles.container}>
           <Camera 
             ref={(cam) => {
               this.camera = cam;
             }}
             style={styles.preview}
             aspect={Camera.constants.Aspect.fill}
             onBarCodeRead={this.readBarcode}>
             <Button
               onPress={() => this.viewProducts}
               title="Products"
             />
          </Camera>
        </View>
      );
   }
}
```

**Router.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import { Icon } from 'react-native-elements';

import Products from '../screens/Products';
import ProductDetail from '../screens/ProductDetail';
import CameraView from '../screens/Camera';

export const Root = StackNavigator({
  Camera: {
    screen: CameraView,
  },
  ProductDetail: {
    screen: ProductDetail,
    navigationOptions: {
      title: ({ state }) => `${state.params.name}}`
    },
  },
  Products: {
    screen: Products,
    navigationOptions: {
      title: 'Products',
    },
  },
});
```

I'm importing CameraView here and using it as the screen for my Camera route. Is CameraView not considered a screen? Thanks.

Comment: Still looking for answers if anyone's able to help.

Answer (score 0):

Figured the problem out. Instead of rendering

```
render() {
    return <CameraView />;
}
```

in my index.js I needed to import the router.js and render

```
render() {
    return <Root />;
}
```